# Python script output redirection using C#

Tags: c#, python, .net, windows, outputstream

this question could seem as duplicate, i have tried all the suggested solution but in vain , i wanna redirect python script output using this code :

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Application.StartupPath.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "") + "\\scripts\\test.py";
    proc.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;

    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 

    proc.Start();
    //proc.WaitForExit();

    StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
    while (!proc.HasExited)
    {
        q.Append(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
    string r = q.ToString();
    r = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(r);
}
private void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    //textOutput.Text += args.Data;
    MessageBox.Show(args.Data);
}
```

the python script contains `print "hello test"` i tried unbuffering output but vainly.

Any help please.

I'm using VS 2010 .NET 4.0 , Python 2.7 , winXP sp3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a StreamReader instance instead of StringBuilder.
this code works for me just fine:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ping.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "8.8.8.8";


        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        proc.Start();
       StreamReader q = proc.StandardOutput;
       while (!proc.HasExited)
         Console.WriteLine(q.ReadLine());

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: and if that doesn't work you could always use the pipe operator to write to a file and read that one

Comment: it hadn't worked, but i need to have the redirected output in realtime

Comment: I added code, it works for me and it prints line by line (maybe not best way to do it, I never learned C#)