# C# - Get Python logging stream

Tags: c#, python, logging

i have a little question. Is it possible to get the logging stream (logging module) from a python script in C# using Process and ProcessStartInfo ?

As example:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;
        start.FileName = "runtime\\bin\\python\\python_mcp";
        start.Arguments = "runtime\\decompile.py %*";
        start.CreateNoWindow = true;
        start.UseShellExecute = false;

        bBuild = true;
        sStatus = "Decompiling...";

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = start;

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { rtOut.Clear(); });
        OutputMsg("========== Decompiling Binaries ==========");

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { proc.Start(); });

        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            OutputMsg(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { proc.WaitForExit(); });
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { proc.Close(); });

        OutputMsg("========== Finished decompiling ==========");
        bBuild = false;
        sStatus = sIdleMessage;
```

but proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine() does not get any output.
The standart print() output from python is caught but not the logging one

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I have seen this question which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671733/python-script-output-redirection-using-c-sharp . If not, can you post the rest of the code where you are attempting to read from the stream?

Comment: i added the whole method i'm using, and like i wrote the standart output by print() in python is displayed

Comment: I finally read your question properly so sorry for the unrelated post before. If you can (and I assume not), you could add a logging handler for the console to the python code and catch that. Otherwise, I don't know of a way to intercept the logging output from System.Process.